# inject into before serialization wcf

Tags: wcf

I want to use IDispatchMessageInspector and BeforeSendReply method to change replay before return to client but it is too late cause message are serialized then.

It is another wcf interface or other way to change data returned by service but not serialized yet?

I want to use data return by service to generate new data and do my own serialization when accept type is text/html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component which converts between the return object and the outgoing message is the `IDispatchMessageFormatter`. Content negotiation (changing the response format depending on the incoming `Accept` header) is doable in the "classic" WCF, but you'll need to write your own formatter to deal with it - on incoming requests it would check what's the accept header and store it somewhere (such as the operation context), and on outgoing responses it would get the value of that header and decide how to format the outgoing response.

With the WCF Web APIs, however, content negotiation is a lot easier, and there are indeed many samples that do exactly that. Check it out at http://wcf.codeplex.com - the Content Manager sample has some content negotiation capabilities.